# Unable to parse a valid Json from Arabic text

Tags: json

This appears to be valid Json but Json parsers throw an exception on address text. Can we not have arabic values as Json values?

```
{
   "deliveryTime":"12:34:00",
   "deliveryDate":"07-09-2017",
   "paymentType":1,
   "deliveryMethod":1,
   "address":{
      "text":"\"7774 جبل الجزيره، طويق"\, "\الرياض \13791 3836، السعودية\"",
      "geo":{
         "latitude":24.580577,
         "longitude":46.518820
      },
      "noteToDriver":"Near bank",
      "country":"Saudi Arabia"
   }
}
```

https://jsonlint.com/ throws an exception but I couldn't figure out the issue. It has double quotes properly escaped, the entire address value is quoted. I think the problem is due to the right to left nature of the language that resulted in the error.

Error: Parse error on line 7:
...4 جبل الجزيره، طويق"\,       "\الرياض \13791
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'

Comment: Paste your exception/logs please.

Comment: "but Json parsers throw an exception" ... what JSON parsers?  What language?  Add some additional tags and some code please.

Comment: I think your json is invalid. value of text key is in valid.Its not an array although your "text" has 2 values.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid where you are using Arabic value. You can validate it on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I have validated the JSON and I'm aware it is the address.text is where the error lies. I don't know how to fix it because I couldn't figure out the error. As suggested, I have pasted the error from JsonLint.

Comment: http://w3c.github.io/i18n-discuss/notes/json-bidi https://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Bidi_in_social_media well, I think you're right about this being the problem with RTL languages representation in JSON. If only there was a good, quick fix for it...